# Block many handlers on condition

Tags: jquery

I have many buttons that have to be self blocked when condition return true. Something like blow not work. How to do that elegant ?

```
$('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(event){
    if(maintence_mode){
        event.preventDefault(); // alerts can't be shown
    }
}); 

$('#button1').click(function(){
   alert('1');
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
   alert('2');
});

$('#button3').click(function(){
   alert('3');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ojd77tqm/)

**Update**:
I have exactly something like below now and doesn't work with `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. I think that requesting `/isservicemode` takes some time...

```
var checkServiceMode = function(callback) {
    $.get('/isservicemode', function(data){
        callback(data.mode);
    }); 
}

$('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(event){
    checkServiceMode(function(modeon){
        if(modeon) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How about a simple return false; ? when condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

You can stopImmediatePropagation. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ojd77tqm/7/)

For demo purpose I have reseted mainence_mode to false after 5 second, so that click works again.

```
var maintence_mode = true;  


$('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(event){
        if(maintence_mode){
            event.preventDefault(); // alerts can't be shown
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }); 
    $('#button1').click(function(){
       alert('1');
    });

    $('#button2').click(function(){
       alert('2');
    });

    $('#button3').click(function(){
       alert('3');
    });

setTimeout(function(){
maintence_mode = false;
},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var maintence_mode = true;  

$('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(event){
        if(maintence_mode){
            event.preventDefault(); // alerts can't be shown
        }
       else{
          alert($(this).text().split("")[1])
        }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ojd77tqm/4/)

Comment: `alert`s are only fillers for simplify example

Answer (score 0):

You should manage your code in else block this:

```
var maintence_mode = true;  
$('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(event){
        if(maintence_mode){
            event.preventDefault(); // alerts can't be shown
        } else{
           $('#button1').click(function(){
       alert('1');
    });

    $('#button2').click(function(){
       alert('2');
    });

    $('#button3').click(function(){
       alert('3');
    }); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event stop propogation function.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e5mkvrjq/

```
var maintence_mode = true;  
$('#button1,#button2,#button3').click(function(event){
    if(maintence_mode){
        event.stopPropogation(); // alerts can't be shown
    }
}); 

$('#button1').click(function(){
   alert('1');
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
   alert('2');
});

$('#button3').click(function(){
   alert('3');
});
```